# android contact number comparison

Tags: java, android, string, contacts

I am trying to retrieve phone numbers from the phone which I have done, then compare the numbers with an online php/sql database.

Everything is working fine except I have one number which will not match correctly even though I know its there.  I have tried testing the number within android only using .equals("same number") and it returns false, even though print statements are identical.  I have definitely removed all white space from the number.

Does anybody have any idea why a number pulled from a phone contactsContract would not be a true string, or have any other ideas!!?? I have tried .toString() also and this doesnt help!

Below is the code I used to test the number being pulled from the Contacts with the relevant ID hard coded in.  The phone number is returned as expected and displays as such in the Log output.  When I try to compare it with a string of identical contents it returns a false!  I can't understand this!

```
Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER},
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID+" = 148" , null, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    tempNum=pCur.getString(0).toString();

                    tempNum=tempNum.trim();
                    tempNum=tempNum.replaceAll("\\s+","");

                } 
               Log.d("tempNum = ", tempNum); //confirm tempNum is as expected
               if(tempNum.equals("07594*****0"))Log.d("test","Match!");
               //number removed after paste to forum
               else Log.d("test","No Match!");
```

Comment: You need to show us your code and also the number from the phone book and the number in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Well my advice is to print the whole array (I guess you store it in an array) in a log.d and see if it is there. Thats is always a tip by the way to clear your mind up when you are in a situation and don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that and everything looks exactly as it should!  As I've just edited above, the two seemingly identical strings wont return a true on a .equals comparison, strange!

Comment: @Jmcg Well I don't know either how you can fix that but, I got one more tip and that is to create a new android project and make a sql database with only that string where you have a problem with. That would make the case more clear and maybe it does work then. Sidenote: Maybe there is something(I do not know what) wrong in your database what is causing this effect.